# React native reducer: How update object value in array

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Good evening. New to react native, I am trying to change the property value of an object in contenur to an array in my reducer. I have tried several of the suggested solutions but it replaces the object in the array with the new value. help me, here is the example of my object redux array

```
[{id:'UniqueId', name, "somename",type:'sometype'},{id:'UniqueId', name, "somename",type:'sometype'},{id:'UniqueId', name, "somename",type:'sometype'}]
```

now I would like to modify the value of the name property of an object contained in the array while knowing its id without touching or remove the other value of the object from the array

Here is my reducer

```
const initialState = { appliance:false }
function authReducer(state=initialState , action) {
    let nextState
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_ALL':
            nextState = {
              ...state,
              appliance:action.value
          }
          return nextState || state
        case 'ADD_DATA':
          nextState = {
            ...state,
            appliance:[...state.appliance, action.value]
        }
        case 'EDIT_NAME':
          return state.map(item => 
            item.id ===  action.value ? { ...item, title, tags, mentions} : item 
           )

      default:
        return state
      }
  }

  export default authReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to make a copy of the current state, modify the copy, and then set the state to that copy:

```js
case 'EDIT_NAME':
          const {id, name} = action.payload;
          const newState = [...state]
          newState.map(item =>
            if(item.id === id)
              item.name = name;
           )
          return newState;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code but first when I use action.payload it gives me an underfine error. I therefore called directly the object's variables but that remove all the content of the redux
` case 'EDIT_NAME':
          //const {id, name} = action.payload;
          const newState = [...state.appliance]
          newState.map(item =>{

            if(item.id ===  action.value.id)
            item.name =  action.value.name;

          })
          return newState;`